# Does php have something to handler semaphores to synchronize reading and writing a json file?

Tags: php, json, synchronization, semaphore

I have a json file. I am not actually reading and writing in a json but getting everything in the file with file_get_contents and after manipulating that putting it in the file using file_put_contents. I want to synchronize it. If a user is working with the file then other users have to wait. I have done similar things in my system programming lab using semaphores. Can I use semaphores with php. If not then what are my alternatives? I hope I have made myself clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're specifically talking about file access, you'd do this with *advisory file locks*: [`flock`](http://php.net/flock). Example:

```
$fp = fopen("/tmp/lock.txt", "r+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {  // acquire an exclusive lock
    ftruncate($fp, 0);      // truncate file
    fwrite($fp, "Write something here\n");
    fflush($fp);            // flush output before releasing the lock
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);    // release the lock
} else {
    echo "Couldn't get the lock!";
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: This is not a text file. This is a json file. And I am not writing on it. I am using file_get_contents and file_put_contents.

Comment: That doesn't matter, you can do the same with a JSON file. And you *are* writing to it if you `file_put_contents`. You simply need to do it using the `fopen` API instead which also allows you to `flock`. The example is simply copied from the manual to illustrate the concept.